# How to use pthreads with Android NDK?

Tags: android, pthreads, android-ndk

As I know pthreads is a part of C library.

Android has Bionic C library.

How to use pthreads with Android NDK?

Answer (score 15):

There isn't a major difference between using pthreads with NDK or otherwise. All syntax is standard UNIX C. You can explore the `pthread.h` located at `$NDK/platforms/android<version>/arch-arm/usr/include`. All you have to do to make that functionality available to you is `#include <pthread.h>`. Build tools will know where to find it. You can see all supported functionality there and it's pretty short.

If you're looking for help learning pthreads, Google is your best friend.