# pthread_cancel not found compiling with android toolchain

Tags: android-ndk, pthreads, cross-compiling

I'm compiling a program that is configured using the Android Toolchain. I'm using ndk r10c. I made a standalone toolchain using

```
$./make-standalone-toolchain.sh --ndk-dir=/home/justin/bin/android-ndk-r10c/ --install-dir=/home/justin/android-toolchain/
```

and was able to configure my project, but when I `make` I get

```
error: 'pthread_cancel' was not declared in this scope
```

The header has `#include <pthread.h>` and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8219978/how-to-use-pthreads-with-android-ndk) seems to indicate that I should be able to use pthreads as I normally would.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Bionic (Android's libc) does not have `pthread_cancel`. IIRC, when we discussed adding this we chose not to because implementation of it is error prone and harmful to performance (of all code).

As far as we could tell, no implementation of pthreads implements a fully correct `pthread_cancel`. It would also impose a cost on all code, even if you're not using `pthread_cancel` (because so many sections of code need to be guarded from interruption by `pthread_cancel`).

Comment: what should one use instead?

Comment: That depends a lot on the situation.

Comment: Have just been caught out in the same way, i.e. porting a threaded lib to android with ndk which called pthread_cancel(). Hopefully GIYF and I'll be able to cobble together an alternative that is in the android pthread header file